# The Instagram API will return an empty json (null)

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

Requests (endpoints):

```
method: "GET"
apiCall: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{id}/relationship?access_token=my.validAccess.token"
paramString: null

method: "POST"
apiCall: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{id}/relationship?access_token=my.validAccess.token"
paramString: "&action=follow"
```

Answers (via PHP json_decode):

`null`

`null`

(not data[], not meta, only null)

At the same time, the GET-request `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=my.validAccess.token&count=20` gives normal information

Application status is a sandbox. User who authorized - in the sandbox. Permissions are all: `['basic', 'public_content', 'follower_list', 'comments', 'relationships', 'likes']`

Comment: You dumped the URL to be sure it's parsing correctly?

Comment: yes, its data from dump, i only replaced access_token for posting on this site